# Is the definite article 'the' necessary in phrases like 'neither of the cats'?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article, quantifiers

When I want to say

- neither of the cats
- either of the cats
- none of the cats
- half the cats
- a lot of the cats
- most of the cats
- each of the cats
- every one of the cats
- all the cats

That 'the' is mandatory or it's up to me if I put it there?

Comment: You can [just about] say things like ***Half of cats are female***, but that's the only one from your list, and it's a bit "awkward", anyway. We'd almost always say *Half of **all** cats are female* - so as a learner your safest bet is to assume you *always* need ***the*** (but note that ***all*** is a kind of "determiner" in such contexts, which is why native speakers would normally include something like that).

Comment: So when I say all a problem it's wrong and I can only say all the problem?

Comment: No, you're completely wrong, there! Where did "problems" come into it? I was talking about references to plural ***cats*** as in all your examples in the question. Your singular "problem" example is completely different (fwiw, we ***do*** say *It's all a problem*, but that's a complex context that would need to be addressed all on its own, imho)

Comment: When you ask here, you should provide examples with each one. Not just list a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

*A lot of **the** cats* is acceptable only when there is a particular set of cats that is mutually understood by speaker and addressee(s) or about to be specified—as in “a lot of the cats brought in to this animal shelter.”

By contrast, *a lot of cats* means many individuals that qualify for the label *cat*.

As is **so** often the case, very much depends on context.

Comment: Can I say a lot of an apple pn only the is suitable herez

Comment: What does that question mean?

Comment: Can I say either of cats without the?

Comment: Or all a problem and not all the problem?

Comment: Well, *either of cats* by itself is not idiomatic. But it would be (barely) okay in a sentence like “The inn doesn’t allow guests to bring **either of cats and dogs**.” As I say, so much depends on context. And anyway, that barely acceptable usage would almost certainly be expressed instead as “The inn doesn’t allow guests to bring **either cats or dogs**.” And depending on what you meant (so on your context), *either of cats* could be replaced by the 100%-idiomatic *either cat*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I'd say ***of*** in contexts like *Their pets are either **of** cats and dogs* is *very* unusual phrasing, and I would strongly advise learners to avoid it. In favour of *Their pets are either cats **or** dogs*, but I don't think the ***and / or*** distinction is pivotal there - it's the word ***of***.

Comment: I agree, @FumbleFingers. In that context, *either of cats and dogs* doesn’t clear even the low bar of “barely okay.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I found a couple of written instances of [*either **of** boiled or roasted*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22either+of+boiled+or+roasted%22), which I find "barely (but *only just*)" acceptable. But they're both adjectives rather than plural nouns, which *may* make a difference.

Comment: Here, @FumbleFingers, my acculturation as a mathematician kicks in, leading me to reason as follows. *Either of* requires as a complement a pair of alternatives, and *boiled **or** roasted* isn’t a pair. So I’d go for the wording *either of boiled **and** roasted*. I reiterate, though, that in most contexts, the simpler *either boiled or roasted* would be preferable.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I approximately agree your thinking re using either of ***and*** and (or ***or**!* :) ***or***. Well, I suppose I *completely* agree with the gist of it - I just think I could tolerate either conjunction, assuming I was okay with ***of*** in the first place. But I would "just about" accept all of them.

Comment: Hey @FumbleFingers, look at the title of [the post I just saw turn up on the math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811684/how-many-binary-strings-of-length-10-are-there-that-dont-contain-either-of-the). I was about to apply “my acculturation as a mathematician” when I thought of you :-)

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: Well. you're the one claiming to have the background! I just puzzled over the question for a minute or two whilst assuming there would be a swathe of clear-cut answers underneath - so it was a bit of a surprise when I tried to scroll down and found... ***nothing***. I'm guessing the answer is a fairly big number, because it amounts to "count all possible permutations where every binary digit has *the same* digit before and/or after it" (with a tweak to handle the first and last digit as special cases. I will revisit as soon as I post this comment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149822/discussion-between-paul-tanenbaum-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 0):

In all of those examples that don't use the word *all* or the phrase *a lot*, the *the* is required if you want to sound like a native English speaker, although you may still be understood even if you leave it out. The other two have different meanings depending on whether you include *the*, with the difference in both cases being whether you're referring to a specific set of cats, or just cats in general or an indefinite set of cats.